# Supervisor keep huey python running

Tags: python, redis, supervisord

I'm trying to get supervisor to monitor and maintain a python script that that's using Huey (a redis type queue).

my Supervisor program config looks like this:

```
[program:smsbot_handler]
directory=/home/ubuntu/virt_env/virt1/app/
command=/home/ubuntu/virt_env/virt1/bin/huey_consumer.py main.huey --threads=3
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/smsbot_handler_log.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/ubuntu/virt_env/virt1/app:$PYTHONPATH"
redirect_stderr=true
```

Can anyone give me any clues as why this doesn't work? All i get in my log file is:

```
Error importing main.huey
```

It's really starting to get to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have already tested that your command runs fine when it is not launched from supervisor, I would remove the environment line, start a shell script instead, set the environment and launch huey_consumer.py from the shell script (using exec python).

This what I do with all my programs which require a specific environment under supervisor.

Here is an example:

In supervisor configuration:

```
[program:MyExample]
command=/ama/nms/MyExample/supervisor_myexample.sh
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
directory=/ama/nms/MyExample  ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
priority=10                   ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
autorestart=true              ; retstart at unexpected quit (default: true)
startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
startretries=10                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
stopsignal=TERM               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
```

In file /ama/nms/MyExample/supervisor_myexample.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ------------------------------------------

# Set the environment
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<...>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=<...>:$PYTHONPATH

D=`dirname $0`
exec python $D/myexample.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The key point is to launch the command using exec so that supervisor can monitor the pid of the command which is launched.

Comment: How would i start a shell script using Supervisor? I've tried command=script.sh, but that doesn't seem to work?